# Java 8 stream Map<Long, List<MyClass>> to Map<Long, Set<Long>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to convert (using Java 8 stream) a `Map<Long, List<MyClass>>` in a `Map<Long, Set<Long>>` where the `Set<Long>` represents the `id` of each `MyClass` of the `List`.

I have tried:

```
myFirstMap.entrySet().stream()
      .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
          .map(MyClass::getId)
          .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
```

But I cannot see how to get the result.

Comment: Your edit invalidates answers that have been here for a year. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mapping instances of `Map.Entry` to `Set<Long>` instances which implies loosing track of the original map’s keys which makes it impossible to collect them into a new map having the same keys.

The first option is to map the `Map.Entry<Long, List<MyClass>>` instances to `Map.Entry<Long, Set<Long>>` instances and then collect the entries to a new map:

```
Map<Long, Set<Long>> result=
    myFirstMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(),
               e.getValue().stream().map(MyClass::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

The alternative is to fuse the `map` and `collect` step into one, to do the transformation right in the value function provided to the `toMap` collector:

```
Map<Long, Set<Long>> result=
    myFirstMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().stream().map(MyClass::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

This way, you avoid creating new `Map.Entry` instances and get more concise code, however, loose flexibility as you can’t chain additional stream operations in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without the overhead of the outer `Stream` is to use `Map.forEach()` like this:

```
Map<Long,Set<Long>> result = new HashMap<>();
myFirstMap.forEach((k,v) -> 
    result.put(k, v.stream()
        .map(MyClass::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Which is really just a convenience method to do this:

```
Map<Long,Set<Long>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Long, List<MyClass>> entry : myFirstMap.entrySet()) {
    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().stream()
        .map(MyClass::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
}
```